# abbrev vs yasnippet for this use case

Tags: yasnippet, abbrev

I have not done much with abbrev-mode or yasnippet, but I recently started using AucTex mode with great success, and I think some common TeX markup I'm inputting could benefit from expansion.

Example:

- Type `dots` and get `\dots{}`
- Type `txt` and get `\textit{}` (with cursor between the brackets)

I'm a beginner user, and abbrev-mode looks easier. However, I am not sure if it has the funcionality I'm looking for. If it must be Yasnippet, could someone advise on a good tutorial aimed at beginners?

Thank you,
steven arntson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use yasnippet for this, especially because of the desired cursor
placement.

The first snippet could be something like

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: dots
# key: dots
# --
\dots{$0}
```

You should store this file in a directory named `latex-mode` under a
directory that is listed in `yas-snippet-dirs`.  I think the
[official documentation](http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/) is
probably the best place to look for more information, but perhaps that's because I haven't actively looked for other information or tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for this---after some experimentation, it worked perfectly. Furthermore, I learned that once I have the cursor positioned between the brackets, I can add a command to TAB out of them when I'm finished with the entry: `\textit{$1}$0`